Why is this returning nothing?
I am working on an Indeed scraper and I followed a guide and this guide used this code and it returned data, but when I do it it returned blank.
I made sure that <div class="job_seen_beacon"> does exist on the page so the HTML structure is the same as when this tutorial is from.
Here is my code:
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def get_data(s, url):
    r = s.get(url)
    return r.html.find("div.job_seen_beacon")

def parse_html(html):
    pass

def main():
    session = HTMLSession()
    url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=IT&l=Louisville%2C+KY&from=searchOnHP"

    print(get_data(session, url))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I was expecting a list of all instances of "jobe_seen_beacon" but instead got nothing.

Did you consider checking the HTTP status code after GET?

For several reasons.
First, if you inspect the raw_html of your request (for example with print(r.html.raw_html)), you can see that it does not contain job_seen_beacon at all. This is because it is created by javascript, and your current code only fetches the html.
You need to render the page first:
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render()

r.html.find("div.job_seen_beacon")

This executes the javascript and gets the result after that.
However, you might be out of luck, since for me at least this triggers Cloudflare protecion on the site. A snippet from print(r.html.raw_html):

This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.

So you might need to use something else, like cloudscraper, as mentioned here: Python - Request being blocked by Cloudflare.

So that leads to more questions. If it's not part of the HTML why does it show up when I inspect the page (maybe that is something I need to so research on rather than just asking here)
Also, when I add the render, it goes through the Chromium Download, but at the end still returns a blank list. I never get the error you were referring to.

Because when you inspect a page from a browser, the javascript has been already executed, and javascript can add new elements to HTML, that's it's purpose mostly. Oh, and I can see the error by doing the print(r.html.raw_html) after the render. Updated the answer.
